# Scrape Facebook friends with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've already done some basic web scraping with BeautifulSoup. For my next project I've chosen to scrape facebook friend list of a specified user. The problem is, facebook lets you see friend lists of people only if you are logged in. So my question is, can I somehow bypass it and if not, can I make BeautifulSoup act like if it was logged in?

Here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input("enter url: ")

try:
   page = urlopen(url)
except:
   print("Error opening the URL")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "_3i9"})

friends = ''
for i in content.findAll('a'):
    friends = friends + ' ' +  i.text

print(friends)
```

Comment: Facebooks Terms of Service doesn't allow you to scrape them.

Comment: They cannot be scraped if you are not logged in. Then they don't show up. I hope that if I make my script act as if it was logged in, I will be able to scrape them...

Comment: As I said. Facebooks Terms of Service does not allow you to scrape Facebook. If your script logs in and scrape the user will be banned.

Comment: With current Facebook censorship. your user will be banned anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup doesn't require that you use an URL. Instead:

1. Inspect the friends list
2. Copy the parent tag containing the list to a new file (ParentTag.html)
3. Open the file as a string, and pass it to BeautifulSoup()

```py
with open("path/to/ParentTag.html", encoding="utf8") as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

4. Then, "you make-a the soup-a."

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, facebook lets you see friend lists of people only if
>   you are logged in

You can overcome this using Selenium. You'll need it to authenticate yourself, then you can find the user. Once you found it, you can proceed in two ways:

- You can get the HTML source with `driver.page_source`and from there use Beatiful Soup
- Use the methods that Selenium provide you to scrape friends

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely try that. If I have any questions. I'll leave 'em here.